# How many but strings of length 7 either begin with three zeros or end with two zeros

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Number of bitstring of length 7 beginning with 3 zeros or ending with two zeros

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  For instance, have you counted the number of bit strings with length $7$ which begin with three zeros? end with two zeros?  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: For a set $S$ with a finite number of elements, let $|S|$ denote the number of elements in the set $S$.  Then, you have the general formula for sets $A,B$ each with a finite number of elements of $$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|.$$